# Basic ul li elements in JavaScript listeners

Tags: javascript, html, html5

I am learning JavaScript and I have written a code snippet. Can someone suggest some improvements?

```js
Array.prototype.pushIfDoesntExist = function (item){
    if(this.indexOf(item) === -1) {
        this.push(item);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

var Testing = {
  clickedList: [],
  applyListeners: function() {
       var self = this;
          var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) { 
           document.getElementsByTagName('li')[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
             //we only want to display an item once
             self.clickedList.pushIfDoesntExist(this.textContent)
              self.displayData();
           });
      }
    },
    displayData: function() {
      var textBox = document.getElementById('clickedElements');
        textBox.textContent = this.clickedList.join(', ');
    }
}

Testing.applyListeners();
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Eggs</li>
  <li>Bacon</li>
  <li>Cheese</li>
</ul>
<div id="clickedElements">
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should extract the logic `if(this.indexOf(item) === -1)` into its own function like `if(itemDoesNotExist(this, item))` to make the code more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't Modify `Array.prototype`**

Writing custom functions to built in prototypes is generally a bad idea. The basic reasoning behind this is that it is a bad practice to modify something you don't own, but check out this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859828/javascript-what-dangers-are-in-extending-array-prototype) for more info.

Instead of changing the prototype you could just write a global function:

```
function pushIfDoesntExist(array, item) {
  if (array.indexOf(item) === -1) {
    array.push(item);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

**Weigh Out Pros and Cons before Abstracting**

The function `pushIfDoesNotExist` is well named, so it can act as a comment for what the code is doing. Also, I can think of several of cases where it could be useful. *BUT* is it really worth writing a function for it? After all, you wouldn't write a function `add1`:

```
function add1(number) {
  return number + 1;
}
```

And that's a well named function with even more applications than `pushIfDoesNotExist`. What I'm trying to get at here is that abstracting a part of code is not *always* a good idea. There are some downsides to making a function for something:

1. The function delocalizes code. Someone who is reading through your code to better understand it needs to hunt down where `pushIfDoesNotExist` is defined to see how it works. (good documentation can help with this)
2. It adds a dependency. Functions that call `pushIfDoesNotExist` rely on `pushIfDoesNotExist` being defined properly. (unit tests can help with this)
3. It takes time to write/debug/unit-test/document/maintain/think-about `pushIfDoesnNotExist`.

Is the value added by the function `pushIfDoesntExist` really worth the cost? (especially since you only call it once)

**Inline Module Constructor**

If you want private member variables, or you don't like using `this` or `self` you can use an inline function to construct your `Testing` object.

```
var Testing = (function () {
  var clickedList = []; //hidden inside inline function scope

  function applyListeners() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("li").forEach(function (node) {
      if (clickedList.indexOf(elem.textContent) === -1) {
        clickecList.push(node.textContent);
        displayData();
      }
    });
  }

  function displayData() {
    document.getElementById("clickedElements").textContent = clickedList.join(", ");
  }

  return {
    applyListeners: applyListeners // public
  };
})();
```